# Smooth Scroll + Div opacity

Tags: jquery, scroll, opacity

For a website that I'm working on I would like to create an internal smooth scroll (#) filter that also reduces the opacity of all divs except for the selected div.

So, on the top of my page there will be this filter (that uses jquery smooth scroll to scroll to the selected div on the page, using this jquery code http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/):

```
<p>Filter by:</p>
<a href="#sport">Sport</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
<a href="#food">Food</a>
<a href="#drinks">Drinks</a>
```

No problem so far. But now I would like to reduce the opacity off all divs except for the div that has been scrolled to. So if I press "Sport" in my filter, the page should scroll to  and reduce the opacity of the news, food and drinks divs to e.g. 0.4.

Tried to find a solutions but haven't found anything yet. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

**Outcome**

Managed to get it working by adding a .toFilter class to all divs and by using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.filter').click(function() {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);
        $('.toFilter').not(target).animate({ opacity: 0.2 }, 500);
        target.animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo I set up:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/5NR7q/1/

```
var $p = $('p');

$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var $target = $(this.hash);
        if ($target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $target.offset().top
            }, 1000, function() {
                $p.removeClass('dimmed').not($target).addClass('dimmed');
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I recommend to set a specific class on the end of animation that will make necessary elements dimmed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a target variable in the linked code, use that to:

```
$('div').not(target).animate({ opacity: 0.4 }, 1000);
```